# Remove SUID/GUID bits

Tags: security

SUID and SGID files on system are a potential security risk, and should be monitored closely. Is there any file in ubuntu server that recommended to remove SUID/GUID bits from it?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any file in ubuntu server that recommended to remove SUID/GUID bits from it?

If there is it should be reported as a bug or security problem.

Some easy to do check if all is normal:

- Find all SUID/SGID programs on your system, and keep track of what they are, so you are aware of any changes which could indicate a potential intruder. Use the following command to find all SUID/SGID programs on your system:

  ```
  sudo su  
  find / -type f \( -perm -04000 -o -perm -02000 \)
  ```
- You can set logging on SUID with:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install auditd
  ```

  The file `/etc/audit/audit.rules` has a set of rules what it should log in `/var/log/audit/audit.log`